# Not able to import PySimpleGUI in mac m1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pysimplegui

```
atal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00000001d7a61c40 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1381 in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1414 in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 925 in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1058 in _handle_fromlist
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 674 in __GTIve4UA_from_global_variable
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 651 in __GTIve4UA
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 79 in __38ENUi
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 694 in __ZgKqhDx
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 204 in __k0vNO1JG
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 975 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 985 in __oR3kmMP4
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17471 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10213 in _Show
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10480 in _read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10402 in read
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21738 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21697 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/nishantbhavsar/PycharmProjects/ToDoList_APP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16556 in PackFormIntoFrame
  ...

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Whenever I try to use PySimpleGUI I am facing this problem.I am using Pycharm and on m1 mac.I have also tried installing it from Pycharm's in built package installer but it still shows the same error.

```
import functions
import tkinter
import PySimpleGUI
```

I am creating a to-do list app with python using PySimpleGUI as a module and wanted it to simply get `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Open an issue on the PySimpleGUI GitHub.  Be sure and include information about the Python interpreter, PySimpleGUI version, etc.  And also your layout info.  It appears to be a recursive loop trying to show an error.